# Display Custom Contact Facet data under one report in Sitecore 8.2

Tags: xdb, contact-facets

I have data stored under a custom contact facet in xDB in `Sitecore 8.2`.

I need to display those custom facets information under a single report.

I know I can add this info into Experience Profile. But, what I need is a way to display all the facets created under a single report instead of displaying the facet information under a given user's profile.

Is there any inbuilt report that already exists with this requirement ? Highly appreciate if any thought on a way I can achieve this.

Example scenario would be:
User adds items to a wishlist. We are keeping those wishlist data in a custom facet. Administrators needs to view all the wishlists created by all the users as a single report in Experience Analytics tool or some other place as a custom report.

Comment: Could you please add here screenshot where you hightlight place where list of facets should be shown? It is not clear where in Sitecore should be report shown. IMHO Experience Profile and custom tab is best location for these kind of information. Why you cannot use this?

Comment: Example scenario would be, user adds items to a wishlist. We are keeping those wishlist data in a custom facet. Administrators needs to view all the wishlists created by all the users as a single report in Experience Analytics tool or some other place as a custom report. Updated the ticket with this.

Comment: Can you take a look here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8766/custom-report-from-xdb-mongodb-based-in-geo-ips? I think that they are solving similar problem? One of answers has also sample code. Would that work for you?

Comment: @chorpo Thank you for the link. I think we will go with custom scrips for mongoDb and export them to some file format. Can you please add your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use similar approach as stated in this question also for custom contact facets - [Custom Report from xDB (MongoDB) based in Geo Ips](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8766/custom-report-from-xdb-mongodb-based-in-geo-ips).

Custom "select" from mongoDB will be best for your case and scenario.

Comment: Thanks. I will use the custom script for mongoDB option and export data into file